# Is my Web-Server Deployment is fine?

Tags: sql-server-2008, deployment, iis-7, web-deployment

I'm going to deploy an IIS 7 Web Server for my **ASP.NET MVC 4** Application.

**Windows Server 2008**

**IIS 7**

**SQL Server 2008**

I'm going to do this:
[image: Deployment schema]

In my application:

***Each customer have to use two database**

- First DB: Their **own database**(each customer have one)
- Second DB: The **Global Database** (all customer have the same one)

And the **First DB can join to the second DB**.

(I'm going to use `Server Binding`)

And **about Web-server**:

- Each customer have their **own Web-site** (on the same IIS Web Server) to get the View/UI
- All customer have the **same `API Web Server`** (this one will do everything: get data from database, add/remove data,...)
- Each customer have one Search-Engine(Suggestion tool), to use this tool, I have to **load all relative data into Memory**(reload this data each 4 hours)

This is the first time I have to deploy a server like this, so I don't know how to do the best...

If there are any advises, suggest, reference, books,...please send it to me.
Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIS and SQL Server already cache things in memory for performance, provided there is enough memory and the programming allows it. You don't need to write a special module to do this.

You don't need `Server Binding` to join across databases in SQL Server. You just join accross the database in your SQL (provided they are on the same server)

```
SELECT D1.F1, D2.F2
FROM
ClientDatabase.dbo.Table1 D1
INNER JOIN
GlobalDatabase.dbo.Table2 D2
ON D1.Key = D2.Key
```

SQL Server already comes with a text search engine http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx

Will you be searching text within database records, or will you be searching text in external documents (i.e. Word, PDF)

It appears you are reinventing the wheel. You are more likely to have success if you use pre-built proven components!

Comment: Thank you very much, It's helpful to use `join across DB` instead of `Server binding` in the same Server .
About `searching text` I can't use text-search engine in SQL Server 2008 because The performance is not good.
My Searching tool require < 200 ms in response time. (It looks like keywords suggestion in Google), and I have to joint at least 6 tables to do that search.

I'm going to build an API Web Server because I have to write the same Application/new-version for Smart Phone in future...

Comment: text search builds a catalog from existing data and you search the catalog not the tables. Your in memory API will be doing the same thing as inbuilt text search - joining six tables to get data into a cache/catalog. In both cases the search will be fast but stale. YOu might want to still consider it.

Comment: hey @ElectricLlama Do you have any solution about `Indexed view` for `cross database joins`- In SQL-Server we can't CREATE a `VIEW with SCHEMABINDING`...

Comment: What's the purpose of creating an indexed view? There will still be a stale data issue. I think you should mark changed records in your database then incrementally update your catalog, assuming the catalog gives the desired performance.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I want to create an `indexed view`:
1. to `speed up`!.
2. to use `full text search` in View - because `full text search` require `unique, single-column, non-nullable index`(this mean It require `SCHEMABINDING` on VIEW )

I'm not a DBA , so sorry if I said something wrong

Comment: An indexed view will speed things up but data can be old and/or you will impact inserts/update performance. You should read a bit more about indexed views to understand this. You could instead load your 6 table join into a table that has an identity column on it, then catalog that. It is a long time since I used full text catalogs so despite my prior comments it may still not be a suitable solution, but I think it is worth pursuing some way before you start rolling your own code. You also need to validate that using a full text catalog will provide the performance you require.